# Why is c-array declared at variable-name, instead of type

Tags: c, arrays, types, syntax, declaration

### Introduction

In c, the syntax of declaring a variable of a **given type** goes like this:

```c
// <variable-type> <variable-name>
// for example:
int foo;
```

To declare a **pointer**, you use the **asterisk(*)**, either behind the type, or in front of the variable-name.

```c
int* bar;
int *foobar;
```

This pointer could also point not to a single element, but to an **array** of elements of the **given datatype**.
For example, an array of characters (a string):

```c
char* oneString = "this is a string";
```

The **alternate declaration**(edit: although definitely not equivalent, as pointed out in the comments) of such a string then looks like the following:

```c
//<variable-type> <variable-name>[<count>]
//example:
char anotherString[1024] = "this is another string";
```

In **c# for comparison**, you have it the other way around:

```cs
int[] intArray;
```

### Main-Question:

What were the considerations of effectively declaring an array at the **variable-name**, **instead of its type?**

### As a context/ for comparison

*(not intended as another question, only to provide means of comparing design-decisions)*
What might have been the reasons for the people creating c#, to break with this rule, and move the array-declaration to the type itself?

Comment: How would you declare an array of pointers to functions in C# syntax?

Comment: `char *s = "foo"` and `char s[4]="foo"` are not **"alternate declarations"** of the same thing. They're completely different (`s[1]='x'` is only defined with one of them, and `s="bar"` is only accepted by the other).  I suggest you clear up some of your confusions by reading a book like the K&R manual. As to why it's that way in C#, it's because they copied from Java ;-)

Comment: @melpomene i think i would try to avoid it because of the managed nature of c#.. if i needed references to functions, i would use something inbuilt like a `delegate`, or `Func`.
As for the array of pointers, syntax-wise(ignoring if it is a good idea or not) i would do something along the lines of:
`<data-type>*[] arrayOfPointers = new <data-type>*[<count>];`

Comment: @mosvy , thank you for the clarification, and the suggestion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The alternate declaration of such a string then looks like the following

It is a declaration of a different thing. It is not an alternative to the first declaration. In some contexts you can use them interchangeably, in other contexts you cannot.

> In c# for comparison, you have it the other way around

Different languages are different.

> What were the considerations of effectively declaring an array at the variable-name, instead of its type?

The design consideration was "declaration follows use". This means that if you are using a variable like this: `a[i]` and the result is `int`, you declare it like this: `int a[N];`. If you use it like this `*a`, you declare `int *a`. If you need `*a[i]`, declare `int *a[N]`, and if you need `(*a)[i]`, declare `int (*a)[N]`.

> What might have been the reasons for the people creating c#, to break with this rule

The designers of C# have decided that the "declaration follows use" principle is confusing and not needed in their language. You decide if they were right.